# Main XIB not showing?

Tags: ios, delegates, xib

I currently am having a issue with my main XIB.

I am using iOS 5 Beta 7 so it shouldn't be a problem with that. Anyway, this is how I am doing it in the app delegate to show the main view:

**.h**

```
UIWindow *window;
Game3ViewController *viewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Game3ViewController *viewController;
```

**.m**

```
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
```

In the applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

```
//self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[Game3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Game3ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

Then the dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [_window release];
    [_viewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The problem is that I am not sure if I am now supposed to do something in the MainWindow.XIB, am I? I thought this code would do everything for me but all I see when I load the app is a white window. Am I supposed to connect my Main View in the MainWindow.xib?

Anyway, if you look at Xcode's default templates for a Single View Application in Xcode Beta 7, you will see that there **isn't even a MainWindow.xib**, so that is why I am confused.
How would I go upon fixing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a Single View Application it will create 2 .xib. One is MainWindow.xib and the other is ViewController.xib.
By default you shouldn't have to touch your App delegate because both nibs are linked already.

However, if you want to start from scratch by selecting the Window-based Template you will have to create your own View Controller later. And then to add the view controller to the window you need to do everything you have done with this in your applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

```
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[[Game3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Game3ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

By this I mean that you need to eliminate the first line where you are allocating your window. MainWindow.xib already does it for you.

Comment: The first part is not true for iOS 5. It only has one XIB and that is the View Controller, I don't see any MainWindow.XIB. Edit: I deleted that first line where I allocate the UIWindow and it still doesn't show my View Controller, but it now says this in the console: Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch' Also I edited my code to reflect the current state I am in

Comment: How about eliminating this line self.viewController = [[[Game3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Game3ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
 and then adding the View Controller in Interface Builder

Comment: Should I still delete the UIWindow allocate lines? Also should I make my UIWindow and View Controller an IBOutlet then just connect it in the mainwindow.xib?

Comment: ah yes sorry I missed that part. Both UIWindow and ViewController should be IBOutlets if you are setting them up in Interface Builder.

Comment: However I got a question... Did you use the Window-based Template?  Even that template already has UIWindow as an IBOutlet. So I am confused why you didn't have it before.

Comment: It was a View Based Application back when I started this project back in iOS 4's Xcode

Comment: oh yay! I can upvote too now :D    Thank you. I am new to stackoverflow.